# changed meta tag content attribute values in javascript is not affected in twitter tweets

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I am having these meta tags for Twitter site:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@test" />
<meta id="metaTwtTitle" name="twitter:title" content="" />
<meta id="metaTwtDesc" name="twitter:description" content="" />
<meta id="metaTwtImg" name="twitter:image" content="" />
```

And I am setting up content attribute values of Meta tag through javascript like this

```
document.getElementById("metaTwtTitle").setAttribute("content", document.querySelector('meta[name="description"]').getAttribute("content"));

document.getElementById("metaTwtDesc").setAttribute("content", document.querySelector('meta[name="description"]').getAttribute("content"));

document.getElementById("metaTwtImg").setAttribute("content", document.querySelector('meta[name="og\\:image"]').getAttribute("content"));
```

But the data that are dynamically assigned is not populated in twitter tweets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. Most systems which gather metadata from pages do not execute client side JavaScript.

Use server side code to provide such data reliably.

Comment: What about embedding javascript code within the element?

Comment: @dineshsns — HTML doesn't provide any means to do that … even if it did, if the client doesn't execute JavaScript then it still wouldn't execute JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Quentin for your valuable answers